# Метод возвращающий разные ответы

Tags: c#

Есть строка вот такая строка 
 `Учебная литература  Школьникам и абитуриентам  Дополнительные учебные пособия`,
слова табами. Надо каждое слово записать в отдельную ячейку в базе. 
Как мне это сделать с помощью одного метода?

```
book.Parent_category = ParseCategory(n.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText);
book.Child_category_1 = ParseCategory(n.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText);
```

Итд

То есть строка, на входе всегда одна и та же, но ответ должен быть разный. Понимаю, что можно в метод передать идентификатор и потом ифами выводит ответ. Но есть ли другие решения этой задачи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Непонятно, какого синтаксиса вы хотите. Например, несколько результатов можно упаковать в Tuple, массив или класс.

```
string[] ParseCategory(string content)
{
    return content.Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}

// ...
var arr = ParseCategory(n.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText);
book.Parent_category = arr[0];
book.Child_category_1 = arr[1];
// и т. д.
```

Comment: *"какого синтаксиса вы ходите"* -- звучит угрожающе. Какого синтаксиса вы тут забыли? :D

Comment: @andreycha: Исправил на «хотите» :)

Answer (score 3):

Странный немного вопрос. Ну вообще метод (функция) в программе очень похожа на функцию в математике. То есть если есть f(x1,x2,...xn), то при одинаковых наборах параметров будет один и тот же ответ. Таким образом либо передавайте идентификатор, либо пусть функция сама вызывает другую функцию (или обращается к переменной), чтобы определить, что в данный момент надо вернуть.

Comment: В общем, функцию надо параметризовать.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так, хотя это и довольно некрасиво и не очень-то производительно:

```
int _parsePos;

void ParseReset(){
    _parsePos = 0;
}

string ParseCategory(string value){
    return value.Split('\t')[_parsePos++];
}
```

И затем:

```
ParseReset();
book.Parent_category = ParseCategory(n.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText);
book.Child_category_1 = ParseCategory(n.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText);
```

Или вариант с Enumerator, быстрее и корректнее:

```
string[] ParseCategory(string value){
    return value.Split('\t');
}

using (var categories = ParseCategory(n.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText).GetEnumerator()){    
    book.Parent_category = categories.MoveNext() ? categories.Current : null;
    book.Child_category_1 = categories.MoveNext() ? categories.Current : null;
}
```

Comment: Вариант с энумератором красивый, да.